# How we can integrate PHP in Google Calender API without Zend

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

How we can integrate PHP in Google Calender API without Zend?while i google it i am only getting Code based on Zend Framework.
I CANT ADD A ZEND FRAMEWORK BASED PHP PROJECT AS MY CLIENT IS NOT WILLING TO DO THAT

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate" exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you not satisfied with zend framework? You can use the components separately, without connecting the entire framework.

**[Edit 1]**
Read about this in overview: http://zendframework.com/manual/en/introduction.overview.html
And if you need, I can show you an example.

Comment: i am not familiar with zend,cam i use zend framework and plain php in same project?

Comment: @Alex different from most other frameworks, Zend Framework can be used as a component library, i.e. you can download and use the parts you need only, without having to adopt their MVC application structure.